# Is there a way to turn off sound in firefox from those annoying flash ads?

Tags: firefox

Is there a way to turn off sound in firefox from those annoying flash ads ?

Cause I nearly felt off a chair when one of them caught me off guard a minute ago.

Also, a "flash related" comic from our favourite xkcd.

[image]

Comment: Warning: doing this will also mute youtube or almost any other videosharing site out there.

Comment: Not a big deal, but why didn't you pick my answer as the accepted? i'm just curious, for later answer-improvement purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flashblock will stop the flash animation all together. It puts a play button on all flash content except what you whitelist. The animation will not play until you hit the play button.
[flashblock for firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/433)

Answer (score 4):

FlashBlock will stop any flash items from loading on pages, yet they let you turn on ones you want. I recommend that.

Comment: Yes, but unfortunatelly it blocks those cute little flash games as well.

Comment: Then click on them, they open right back up!

Answer (score 2):

On Vista and Windows 7 you could just mute Firefox in the mixer. Apart from that I don't know of a way. (And yes, Flash ads that have sound are definitely a peak of evil.)

You may just try blocking everything that looks like an ad. [AdBlock Plus](http://adblockplus.org/en/) and [NoScript](http://noscript.net/) work pretty well in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

Banner ads are the necessary evil of the internet - so many companies rely on banner ads to eek out a bit of revenue.  But there's a time and a place for them, and trying to read a news story or blog entry with 200 really annoying "look at me now" banners and strips just makes it worthless.

[Flashblock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search?q=flashblock&cat=all) will do the trick, but [AdBlock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1865) will *silence* them forever - as in, if it doesn't load, it doesn't play.  Set the regex settings to a site to download from regularly and you won't see them, period.

Answer (score 0):

The extension, **[Muter](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/muter/)**, can toggle sounds on/off for the whole browser.